# Who is the Doctor who broke the promise?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of Series 7,

> When Clara jumps into the Doctor's timeline, the Doctor follows her to pull her out. While there, they witness "The Doctor who broke the promise", the promise being the name *Doctor*.

Who is this Doctor, The Doctor who broke the promise?

Is it one of the actors from the 60's series?
The Doctor who fought in the time war?
Someone else?

Comment: It was the war doctor, yes.

Comment: Keep watching...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I just noticed something and didn't really want to Google it because I was afraid of spoilers

Comment: Yes that's correct, lol

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### It was the War Doctor.

Also known as the Eight-and-a-Halfth Doctor, or the Doctor who wasn't really the Doctor, or the Warrior. Played by John Hurt:

[image: Doctor]

**He broke the promise that made him the Doctor, by taking part in the Time War.**

In the online minisode *Night of the Doctor*, when the Eighth Doctor (Paul McGann) regenerates into this new body, he leaves behind the name of Doctor and becomes instead a Warrior, in order to play his part in the Time War he's been avoiding for so long:

> OHILA: Then she was wiser than you. She understood there was no escaping **the Time War. You are a part of this, Doctor, whether you like it or not.**
>   [...]
>   DOCTOR: Warrior.
>   OHILA: Warrior?
>   DOCTOR: I don't suppose there's a need for a doctor any more. Make me a warrior now.
>   [...]
>   (The Doctor drinks the elixir and staggers, dropping the chalice. Regeneration energy starts to surge through his body. He doubles over. White out.)
>   OHILA: Is it done?
>   (A figure takes Cass's baldric and puts it on.)
>   **WARRIOR: Doctor no more.**
>   (We are shown the reflection of a young John Hurt.)
>
> <sub>-- *The Night of the Doctor* (2013) (emphasis mine)</sub>

And in the 50th anniversary special *The Day of the Doctor*, the promise is discussed explicitly:

> CLARA: We've got enough warriors. Any old idiot can be a hero.
>   DOCTOR: Then what do I do?
>   CLARA: What you've always done. Be a doctor. You told me **the name you chose was a promise.** What was the promise?
>   (The fighting seems to have stopped on Gallifrey.)
>   DOCTOR 10: **Never cruel or cowardly.**
>   WARRIOR: **Never give up, never give in.**
>
> <sub>-- *The Day of the Doctor* (2013) (emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: Never surrender!

Answer (score 4):

**The Doctor referred to was the War Doctor (the 9th regeneration, played by John Hurt)**

The promise referred to was the "Never cruel or cowardly. Never give up, never give in."

[SFF question regarding the promise specifically](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110220/hasnt-the-doctor-broken-his-promise-before).

Comment: 9th? I prefer "eight-and-a-halfth-or-something".

Comment: @randal'thor eh, the regeneration was number 9.

Comment: "Lots of planets have a Nine!"

Comment: @cde Blame Eccleston and Moffat/BBC for failing to reach an agreement. :(

Comment: The _incarnation_ was number 9, following the _eighth_ regeneration! (Doctor/incarnation #1 had no prior regenerations.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, but the first doctor of the 2005 series is usually reffered to as the *9th* doctor.

Comment: @Travis: Yes, the 9th doctor. But he was the 10th incarnation, and had had only nine regenerations when he was that guy.

Comment: @Travis: The "War doctor" was the 9th incarnation, and had had only eight regenerations when he was that guy. (Thus certainly wasn't "the 9th regeneration")

Comment: @Travis: The two oddities kind of cancel out after that point. Then go backwards again when Ten semi-regenerates! The 11th Doctor was the 13th incarnation, and had had twelve regenerations. Lol.